# Почему не работает свойство backdrop-filter: blur в модальном окне fancybox?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Мне нужно добавить свойство backdrop-filter для фона в модальном окне fancybox.

Я нашел класс fancybox-bg соответствующий этому фону и добавил backdrop-filter

Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой, я не могу понять, почему backdrop-filter не работает.
Спасибо за ответ.

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-germain-bxb5jy?file=/src/styles.css:514-525

Comment: не стоит использовать это свойство, работает только на хромиуме

Comment: мне нужно его использовать, хотя бы в хроме, так как оно нарисовано на макете.